# Output has an "Unknown" status?

Tags: transactions, address, multi-signature

Looking at transaction https://blockstream.info/tx/c362fe7f8cb94b363c0c7cd5a0f82cf0dfa7733ab8a3b90df3eb9f0bff912148 some outputs are having type: `nonstandard`.

There are 2 questions related to it:

1. Wouldn't this construct be interesting from the perspective of obscuring data against blockchain analytics?
2. Where can I learn more about transactions like this one? Why does it have something that looks like a multisig definition in the output?

Comment: Those are bare multisig outputs, which are in fact standard. There just is no address format for them.

Comment: If it's the standard, is there a place I can read more about it? Maybe it was introduced in some BIP?

Comment: Standardness is generally not specified in BIPs, as it is up to individual nodes to decide, and depends on the exact software you're using and what version. Bare multisig is accepted by most nodes, though.